# Getting Blank Screen in webview when bypassing SSL Error

Tags: android, ssl, webview, android-webview, sslerrorhandler

I know that SSL `handler.proceed()` is not allowed on the playstore. And they reject the app once their bots able to find the same in the uploaded app. For testing purpose I was asked to share the UAT APK with this SSL bypass only for UAT environment. When I am trying to use `handler.proceed()`, I get a blank screen with below error

> Ignoring unexpected ssl error proceed callback

in the logcat. I have searched the whole internet and I found nothing useful yet. Below is my code.

```
override fun onReceivedSslError(view: WebView?, handler: SslErrorHandler, er: SslError?) {
        super.onReceivedSslError(view, handler, er)
        LogHelper.e("check error", "onReceivedError")
        showErrorDialog(handler, er)
}

private fun showErrorDialog(handler: SslErrorHandler, error: SslError?) {
        val builder = activity?.let { AlertDialog.Builder(it) }

        var message = "SSL Certificate error."
        when (error?.primaryError) {
            SslError.SSL_UNTRUSTED -> message = "The certificate authority is not trusted."
            SslError.SSL_EXPIRED -> message = "The certificate has expired."
            SslError.SSL_IDMISMATCH -> message = "The certificate Hostname mismatch."
            SslError.SSL_NOTYETVALID -> message = "The certificate is not yet valid."
        }

        message += " Do you want to continue anyway?"

        builder?.setTitle("SSL Certificate Error");
        builder?.setMessage(message)
        builder?.setPositiveButton(activity?.getString(R.string.button_continue)) { dialog, _ ->
            dialog.dismiss()
            handler.proceed()
        }

        builder?.setNegativeButton(activity?.getString(R.string.cancel)) { _, _ ->
            handler.cancel()
            activity?.onBackPressed()
        }
        builder?.create()?.show()
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Below is the solution. No need to call the `super.onReceivedSslError(view, handler, er)` as we need handle this on our side only. Although this does not prevent your app from playstore rejection.

```
override fun onReceivedSslError(view: WebView?, handler: SslErrorHandler, er: SslError?) {
        //super.onReceivedSslError(view, handler, er)
        LogHelper.e("check error", "onReceivedError")
        showErrorDialog(handler, er)
}
```